# Get Window from Item

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

In QML is there a way of getting the top-level `Window` of any visual object?  Preferably without recursing up through the visual `parent` hierarchy.

I'm trying to find the geometry of the top-level window, so descendent objects can detect if their bounds have crossed the window's.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtquick/qquickitem.html#window

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Thanks, but was I curious from the QML side.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are `Window` properties attached to all `Item`s. Which ones depend on Qt version. E.g. `Window.width` is the current top level window/view width.

You can get a particular `Item`'s `Window` with `myItem.Window`;

With Qt 5.7+ you even get access to all the `Window` properties via `Window.window`.

See docs: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-window-window.html#attached-properties

Comment: This method should be preferred than the accepted answer as it answers the question without extra C++ code. To use the attached `Window.window` property, import the window package in the QML file: `import QtQuick.Window 2.2`.

Comment: Yes! `import QtQuick.Window 2.2` must be present, otherwise it just does not work, despite the fact that there is no runtime errors.

Answer (score 3):

I guess the answer at the moment is "No". This looks like a feature suggestion that can be sent to the QML team.

I ended up exporting my own C++ class to QML.

ItemWithWindow.h:

```
#include <QQuickItem>

class ItemWithWindow : public QQuickItem
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    Q_PROPERTY( QQuickWindow* window READ window NOTIFY windowChanged )

signals:

    void windowChanged();
};
```

(which gets registered as usual with `qmlRegisterType<ItemWithWindow>( uri, 1, 0, "ItemWithWindow" );`)